# How to compile play framework on intellij first time?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, playframework

Im running on ubuntu Intellij ultimate edition, and i've got this error

```
Error:(20, 19) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable index
  location: class controllers.HomeController
```

im running on first time, so i've got no idea why this is happening. I've already search and make twirl/main as source folder, but in my case directory scala-2.11  only contain classes folder. Already mark that as a root, didn't work as well. What should i do?

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmVms.png)

Comment: could you provide path for your index template?

Comment: where can i find index template?

Comment: in general it should be under `/app/views/`  as  `index.scala.html`